# AC-3 and E-AC-3 passthrough with HLS

Tags: google-cast

I'm developing a web receiver for chromecast.

According to chromecast documentation, HLS with AC-3 passthrough is supported. It is to be checked with canDisplayType and following that, I assume it should be okay to use the codec.

I cannot seem to get the chromecast to accept HLS manifests with AC-3 in the codec list. I have tried this on chromecast generation gen2 and gen3 and they both reject it. canDisplayType will return true or false depending on the settings made in the Google Home app. When I have the server actually send ac-3, it throws `cast.player.api.ErrorCode.MANIFEST/411`, aborts and does not request anything else from the server.

I also cannot seem to get any detailed reason for this, it would be helpful if I was told in the logs why the codec presumably got rejected.

Here's a typical manifest.m3u8 file that I have experimented with:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=5499178,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=5499178,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.a5",RESOLUTION=720x576,FRAME-RATE=50
main.m3u8?<snip>&VideoCodec=h264&AudioCodec=ac3,aac,mp3&<snip>&TranscodingMaxAudioChannels=6&<snip>&h264-profile=high,main,baseline,constrainedbaseline&h264-level=41&<snip>
```

From my experimentation, `mp4a.a5`, `mp4a.A5` and `ac-3` all pass the canDisplayType test but fail at this stage.

For instance:

```
> context.canDisplayType("video/mp4", "avc1.640028,mp4a.a5", 1920, 1080, 50)
< true
```

I have also tried to trick the player by substituting the value with mp4a.40.2 or just pretending like there is no audio. In this case the results vary a bit but generally it requests some `.ts` files before it gives up, or it does not play an audio track at all. In comparison, the same media transcoded using aac-lc 2ch works fine.

Is there anything special one has to do to prepare the receiver to use passthrough audio?